# Java formatting set width and alignemnt with outputFile

Tags: java

I need help formatting output to a file in java. I wrote something like this my first year of c++ and it came out good even if it is sloppy code, but what is the correct way to do this is java?

```
outputFile << left << setw(19) << teamMemberName << right << "|" << left << setw(25) << titleName << right << "|" << left  << "$" << setw(7) << hoursWorked << right << "|" << left  << "$" << setw(14) << payRate << right << "|" << left  << "$" << setw(18) << teamMemberAmmount << endl;
```

I have this so far in java:

```
outputFile.println(memberName + "\t\t"  + "|" +titleName + "\t\t"  + "|" + hoursWorked + "\t\t"  + "|" +(df.format(payRate)) + "\t\t" + "|" +(df.format(teamMemberAmount)));
```

Comment: Use `printf` or `String.format`; see also [Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) and [Customizing Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).

Comment: what class is `outputFile` and `df`?

Comment: DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("invoice.txt");